# SMTP alias not working internally

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2007

I deleted an exchange mailbox (soft delete by deleting the AD account) and then added their email address to a distro list's SMTP list.

Emails externally are working fine, but emails internally are bouncing back -- even with people that have never emailed the user before.

Exchange 2007

Part of the bounce message

```
#550 5.1.1 RESOLVER.ADR.ExRecipNotFound; not found ##
```